# Cannot integrate large exponentials in Python (on Spyder) due to overlfow enecountered in exp, but works on WolframAlpha

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, wolframalpha, exp

I have been trying to replicate Figures 1 and 2 from O'Dwyer's paper, "Electronic and thermal transport in hot carrier solar cells with low-dimensional contacts" ([Link to O'Dwyer Paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0026269207002157)), with Python on Spyder.

## Figures to replicate

#### Figure 1: w = 1e-5

[Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mqM7.jpg)

#### Figure 2 = w = 1e-2

[Figure 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCMcC.jpg)

## Method

To find the absorber temperature, T_H, one needs to equate the *net incoming energy flow due to radiation, Qrad,* and the *net heat current flowing out of the hot absorber reservoir, Qabs.* Their equations are as follows:

[Equations for Qrad and Qabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ki8QA.jpg)

The bold lined plots from Figures 1 and 2 refer to Wurfel's solutions that are given by the following equations:

[Wurfel's Solutions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78J3j.jpg)

I am having some success replicating Figure 2 where w=1e-2 (my results shown below) but have no success getting Figure 1 where w=1e-5 (points and num_T below refer to the number of plotting points and the number of temperatures to iterate through respectively).

#### My attempt at Figure 2 when w=1e-2, points = 21, num_T = 300

[My attempt at Figure 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWDdL.jpg)

I think I am currently having trouble with the "overflow encountered in exp" warning trying to get Figure 1 with w=1e-5 to work. When I try to calculate Qabs (refer to code below in 'Parameters' function), it gives absurd values with orders of magnitude ~1e-70. However, when I run the same equations in WolframAlpha, I get a more reasonable result.

For example, the T_H value when W = 1e-5, N = 1e12 and Voltage = 0 V is ~T_H = 1448K (refer to Figure 1, top left graph).Using WolframAlpha, I get 4.54986×10^22 for Qrad and 4.83602×10^22 for Qabs ([WolframAlpha solution for Qrad at w=1e-5,N=1e12,V=0](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+from+0+to+inf%3A+%282*pi*1.0e-4%29%2F%28%284.14e-15%29%5E3*%283e8%29%5E2%29*%28x%5E3*%281%2F%28e%5E%28x%2F%288.617e-5*6000%29%29-1%29-1%2F%28e%5E%28x%2F%288.617e-5*1448%29%29-1%29%29%29)) and [WolframAlpha solution for Qabs at w=1e-5,N=1e12,V=0](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+from+0+to+inf%3A+%284.0e12%29%2F%284.14e-15%29*%28x-1%29*%281%2F%28e%5E%28%28x-1%29%2F%288.617e-5*1448%29%29%2B1%29-1%2F%28e%5E%28%28x-1%29%2F%288.617e-5*300%29%29%2B1%29%29*%28e%5E%28-%28x-1%2F2%29%5E2%2F%281.0e-5%29%29%29))) which are the results I want in Python. Find below all my code.

## All Code

```
import os
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, Button
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

from scipy.integrate import quad
from scipy.special import expit

import time
from sympy import symbols, Eq, solve
# import warnings
# warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

t0= time.perf_counter()

directory = r'C:\Users\gyanj\Documents\GADGET BACKUP\University\5th Year\Thesis\Python Simul\ODwyer\Plots'
os.chdir(directory) 

c = 3e8 #speed of light, m/s
q = 1.602e-19 # charge of electron, C
h = 6.626e-34/q #Planck's Constant, eVs
k = 8.617e-5 # Boltzmann's Constant, eVK^-1
stefan = 5.67e-8 #Stefan-Boltzmann's Constant, Wm^-2K^-4
T_C = 300 #Cold Reservoir Temperature, K
T_S = 6000 #Sun Temperature, K
Omega = np.pi #Absorption/Emission Solid Angle, sr
A = 1e-4 #Absorber Area, m^2

points = 21 # Number of plotting points
num_T = 300 #Number of temperatures to iterate through
Temperatures = np.linspace(T_C,T_S,num_T) # array of temperatures

E_u = 1 #Average electrochemical potential of system, eV
V = np.linspace(0,1,points) #V applied symetrically across device

max_lim = np.inf# integral upper limit

W = [1e-2] #Transmission function width
N = [1e9,1e10,1e12] #Number of contacts

#Following block used for progress bar (not relevant to calculations)
global total 
total = len(W)*len(N)*(points)*len(Temperatures)
progress = 0
counter = 0
full_time = 0

#Object containing all relevant parameters
class param:
    def __init__(self, TH, I, P, n, Qrad, Qabs):
        self.TH = TH #Hot reservoir/Absorber Temperature, K
        self.I = I # Current, A/m^2
        self.P = P #Power, W/m^2
        self.n = n #Efficiency
        self.Qrad = Qrad #net incoming energy flow due to radiation
        self.Qabs = Qabs #net heat current flowing out of the hot absorber reservoir

Data = np.empty([len(W),len(N),points], dtype = object) #Contain all param objects

datafile = 'ODwyer.dat'
fout = open(datafile,'w')
fout.write('')
fout.close()

for i in range(len(W)):
    for j in range(len(N)):
        for x in range(points):
            Data[i][j][x] = param(0,0,0,0,0,0)

# Function Paramaters calculates Qrad,Qabs and I for a given T_H,u_H,u_C,N_contact,w,voltage
def Parameters (T_H, u_H, u_C, N_contact, w, voltage):
    eqn1 = lambda E: ((E)**3/(np.exp(E/(k*T_S))-1)-(E)**3/(np.exp(E/(k*T_H))-1))
    Qrad = ((2*Omega*A*q)/((h**3)*(c**2)))*quad(eqn1,0,max_lim)[0]
    eqn2 = lambda E:(E-u_H)*(expit(-(E-u_H)/(k*T_H))-expit(-(E-u_C)/(k*T_C)))*(np.exp(-(E-E_u/2)**2/(w)))
    Qabs = ((4*N_contact*q)/h)*quad(eqn2,0,max_lim)[0]
    if Qabs < 0:
        Qabs = np.inf
    error = abs(Qrad-Qabs)
    eqn3 = lambda E:(expit(-(E-u_H)/(k*T_H))-expit(-(E-u_C)/(k*T_C)))*(np.exp(-(E-E_u/2)**2/(w)))
    I = -((2*N_contact*q)/h)*quad(eqn3,0,max_lim)[0]/A
    fout = open(datafile,'a')
    fout.write('%.2e\t%.2e\t%.1f\t%.2f\t%.2e\t%.2e\n'%(w,N_contact,T_H,voltage,Qrad,Qabs))
    fout.close()
    return error, I, Qrad, Qabs

#Progress bar for simulation time (not relevant for calculations)
def progressbar(progress):
   if (progress >= 0.01):
        t1 = time.perf_counter() - t0
        full_time = t1*1/progress*100
        timeleft = full_time-t1
        if timeleft >= 3600:
            timelefthrs = int(round(timeleft/3600,0))
            timeleftmins = int((timeleft-timelefthrs*3600)%60)
            print('\rSimulation Progress: %.2f%%\t Estimated Time Left: %dh %dm  '%(progress,timelefthrs, timeleftmins), end='')
        elif timeleft >= 60 and timeleft <3600: # in mins
            timeleftmins = int(round(timeleft/60,0))
            timeleftsecs = int((timeleft-timeleftmins*60)%60)
            print('\rSimulation Progress: %.2f%%\t Estimated Time Left: %dm %ds  '%(progress,timeleftmins, timeleftsecs), end='')
        else:
            print('\rSimulation Progress: %.2f%%\t Estimated Time Left: %ds  '%(progress,timeleft), end='')
   else:
        print('\rSimulation Progress: %.2f%%'%(progress), end='') 

def Odwyer(index, counter):
    for j in range(len(N)):
        for i in range(points): #per V
            u_H = E_u+V[i]/2 #Hot absorber electrochemical potential, eV
            u_C = E_u-V[i]/2 #Cold Reservoir electrochemical potential, eV            
            error = np.inf #initialise error between Qrad and Qabs as inf
            for x in range(len(Temperatures)):
                temperature = Temperatures[x]
                diff, I, Qrad, Qabs= Parameters(Temperatures[x], u_H, u_C, N[j], W[index], V[i])
                if diff <= error: #if difference between Qabs and Qrad is smaller than previous error, use this Temperature[x]
                    Data[index][j][i].TH = temperature
                    Data[index][j][i].Qrad = Qrad
                    Data[index][j][i].Qabs = Qabs
                    Data[index][j][i].I = I
                    Data[index][j][i].P = I*V[i]
                    Data[index][j][i].n = I*V[i]/(stefan*(T_S**4))                    
                    error = abs(diff)
                counter += 1
                progress = counter/total*100
                progressbar(progress)
    
    #Plotting        
    
    fig, axs= plt.subplots(2,2, constrained_layout=True)
    
    ax1 = axs[0,0]
    ax2 = axs[0,1]
    ax3 = axs[1,0]
    ax4 = axs[1,1]
    
    for i in range(2):
        for j in range(2):
            axs[i,j].set_xlim(0,1)            
            axs[i,j].xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(0.5))            
            axs[i,j].set_xlabel("Voltage (V)")
    
    ax1.set_ylim(0,T_S) 
    ax1.set_ylabel("TH (K)")
    ax1.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(2000))
    
    ax2.set_ylim(0,1e8) 
    ax2.set_ylabel("I (A/m^2)")
    ax2.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(2e7))
    
    ax3.set_ylim(0,1e8) 
    ax3.set_ylabel("Power (W/m^2)")
    ax3.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(2e7))
    
    ax4.set_ylim(0,1) 
    ax4.set_ylabel("Efficiency")
    ax4.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(0.2))
    
    TH = np.empty([len(N),points])
    I = np.empty([len(N),points])
    P = np.empty([len(N),points])
    n = np.empty([len(N),points])
    
    for j in range(len(N)):
        for x in range(points):
            TH[j][x] = Data[index][j][x].TH
            I[j][x] = Data[index][j][x].I
            P[j][x] = Data[index][j][x].P
            n[j][x] = Data[index][j][x].n
            
    #Wurfel's Solution
    TH_W = []
    I_W = []
    P_W = []
    n_W = []
    
    for x in range(points):
        if V[x] == E_u:
            TH_wurfel = 1e20
        else:
           TH_wurfel = T_C/(1-V[x]/E_u)
        TH_W.append(TH_wurfel)
        Iwurfel = (stefan)/(E_u)*(T_S**4-TH_wurfel**4)
        Pwurfel = stefan*(T_S**4-TH_wurfel**4)*(1-T_C/TH_wurfel)
        nwurfel = (T_S**4-TH_wurfel**4)/(T_S**4)*(1-T_C/TH_wurfel)
        I_W.append(Iwurfel)
        P_W.append(Pwurfel) 
        n_W.append(nwurfel)
    
    linestyles = ['--','-','-.']
    
    for j in range(len(N)):
        for x in range(points):
            if TH[j][x] == T_S:
                TH[j][x] = 1e8
    
        
    for i in range(len(N)):
        ax1.plot(V,TH[i], label='N = %.0e'%N[i], color = 'black', linestyle = linestyles[i], linewidth = 1)
        ax2.plot(V,I[i], label='N = %.0e'%N[i], color = 'black', linestyle = linestyles[i], linewidth = 1)
        ax3.plot(V,P[i], label='N = %.0e'%N[i], color = 'black', linestyle = linestyles[i], linewidth = 1)
        ax4.plot(V,n[i], label='N = %.0e'%N[i], color = 'black', linestyle = linestyles[i], linewidth = 1)
        
    ax1.plot(V,TH_W, color = 'black', label='Wurfel', linewidth = 3)
    ax2.plot(V,I_W, color = 'black', label='Wurfel', linewidth = 3)
    ax3.plot(V,P_W, color = 'black', label='Wurfel', linewidth = 3)
    ax4.plot(V,n_W, color = 'black', label='Wurfel', linewidth = 3)
    
    fig.suptitle('w = %.0e eV' % W[index])
    ax1.legend(loc='upper right', fontsize = 8)
    ax2.legend(loc='upper right', fontsize = 8)
    ax3.legend(loc='upper right', fontsize = 8)
    ax4.legend(loc='upper right', fontsize = 8)
    
    #Saving figure
    
    fig.savefig('w = %.0e eV, pp = %d, num_T = %d.jpg' %(W[index],points,num_T), dpi=800)
    
    return counter

for x in range(len(W)):
    counter = Odwyer(x, counter)
    
# Printing out object values

for x in range(len(W)):
    for j in range(len(N)):
        print('Parameters for W = %0.e, N = %.0e'%(W[x],N[j]))
        for i in range(points):
            print('w = %.0e\tV = %.2f\tTH = %.0f\tQrad = %.2e\tQabs = %.2e\tI = %.2e'%(W[x],V[i],Data[x][j][i].TH,Data[x][j][i].Qrad,Data[x][j][i].Qabs,Data[x][j][i].I))

print('\nComplete!')
```

## What I've tried

I have tried changing the upper limit of the integrals from inf to lower values and although it removed the overflow warning for values ~<15, it made Qabs = 0.00e00. I also tried changing arguments for 'limit' and 'epsabs' in the 'quad' function but couldn't get that to work either. Changing the variables 'points' and 'num_T' did not improve the accuracy of my values either. I have also read and tried solutions from relevant posts regarding overflows such as [Overflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66129766/python-exponential-integration-overflow-encountered-in-exp) but to no avail. This is my first post so if you require any further information from me to fix my problem, feel free to let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick and dirty stdlib (no numpy) script that got something close to the WolframAlpha answer:

```py
from math import exp, pi

C1 = 8.617e-5 * 6000
C2 = 8.617e-5 * 1448

def f(x):
    denom1 = exp(x / C1)
    denom2 = exp(x / C2)
    # did some algebra
    difference = (denom2 - denom1) / (denom1 - 1) / (denom2 - 1)
    return x ** 3 * difference

bins = 10_000
endpoint = 10

total = 0.0
for i in range(1, bins+1):
    x = i * endpoint / bins
    total += f(x)
# account for widths
total *= (endpoint / bins)

scaled = float(total) * 2 * pi * 1e-4 / (4.14e-15)**3 / (3e8)**2

print(scaled)
# 4.549838698077388e+22
```

Part of the problem (I'm guessing, not sure) would be that `1/(a-1) - 1/(b-1)` will be wildly imprecise for a and b close to 1, so you can do some algebra to try and fix that, and make it `(b-a)/(a-1)/(b-1)`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. My results have somewhat improved although still not getting the figures from the paper as certain points, when w=1e-5, are still giving weird values for current (top right figure). The simulation time is also much, much longer than before. Will keep at it.